# Getting a TF203091 error on gated checkin

Tags: tfs, build

When checking in some changes to our TFS 2015.4 server, the vNext build agent had an error while in the "Getting Sources" step. The full error is

`Some items in shelveset <gated checkin shelveset> were not unshelved because Project Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION) does not have Read permission for those items.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the build authorization scope. I had set it to "Current Project", but there was a file I had branched from another team project's branch into this one, so the authorization scope was not able to include that file's branching.

[image]

Changing the scope it to "Project Collection" and re-running the build addressed the problem. I had to do exec the build twice actually as the first time reported...

`The working folder D:\agent006\_work\41\s\SomeTrunk is already in use by the workspace ws_41_7;Project Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION) on computer TFSBUILDSERVER.
Prepare repository failed with exception.`

The second and subsequent builds worked properly.